# Loop Excel Save As

Tags: excel, vba, loops, save-as

I am having a hard time trying to run this code. My objective is to save as the master file ("data entry") and have an filename extension based on another excel file ("Book1"). Here's my code:

```
Sub SaveAsLoop()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim fp, en, strName As String
Dim cRng, c as Range

Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("A1",Range("A121").End(xlup))
For Each c In cRng
strName = c.Value 

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\WFH\data entry.xlsm")

fp = "C:\Users\Desktop\WFH\"
mfn = "data entry - "
en = "xlsm"

wkb.SaveAs Filename:=fp & mfn & strName & en, FileFormat:=52

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next c

End Sub
```

Cell A1 to cell A121 of Book1 contains 121 countries and I want to create 121 copies of data entry.xlsm and have an extension based on cell reference. For ex;

```
Sheet1
A1   | Afghanistan
A2   | Algeria
...    ...
A121 | Serbia
```

And the output should be 121 excel files with filename extension like "data entry - Afghanistan", "data entry - Algeria", ... , "data entry - Serbia".

The problem is, the loop is not working and only work one time, the output only is 1 file with the file name using the cell A1 ("data entry - Afghanistan").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to open the workbook to be copied at each loop. Open it once and use `SaveCopyAs`:

```
Sub SaveAsLoop()
 Dim wkb As Workbook
 Dim fp As String, mfn As String, en As String, strName As String
 Dim cRng As Range, c As Range

 Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
 fp = "C:\Users\Desktop\WFH\"
 mfn = "data entry - "
 en = ".xlsm"
 Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(fp & "data entry.xlsm")


 For Each c In cRng
    strName = c.value
    wkb.SaveCopyAs (fp & mfn & strName & en)
 Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with this:

1. `fp`, `en` and `cRng` are all Variant datatypes as you are explicitly declaring them to be of a certain type;
2. `mfn` is not actually declared;
3. When you are saving the workbook, you are including the file extension "xlsm" as part of the file name, which is not needed as `FileFormat:=52` takes care of this;
4. The main problem is how you are trying to find the last cell to loop to.

As you are not actually doing anything with "data entry.xlsm" when you open it, and you already know how many rows you are going to process, there is a faster way, using the `FileCopy` command:

```
Sub sSaveLoop()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim strFileStub As String
    Dim strFileSource As String
    strFileSource = "C:\Users\Desktop\WFH\data entry.xlsm"
    strFileStub = "C:\Users\Desktop\WFH\data entry - "
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To 121
        FileCopy strFileSource, strFileStub & ActiveSheet.Cells(lngLoop1, 1) & ".xlsm"
    Next lngLoop1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSaveLoop", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: you could remove the `sExit:` "block" completely and the `Resume sExit` statement, too

Comment: And you may want to check for empty cells or loop through not empty ones only, not to raise an error for something that can be taken care of. BTW OP seems to want looping through column A not empty cells down to row 121

Comment: I always write the `sExit`/`E_Handle` blocks, even if they're not needed. It just seems like best practice so I always have a place to do cleanup of anything that has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think If Cell A1 to cell A121 of Book1 contains 121 countries  then output of this code:

```
Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("A1",Range("A121").End(xlup))
```

is Range("A1") so loop make it only once

Try

```
Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("A1",Range("A" & Range("A:A").Count).End(xlup))
```

Or

```
Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("A1",Range("A1")).End(xldown)
```