# VBA Excel cell.value does not show any value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to develop the loop for saveAs the files

[Loop Excel Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171873/loop-excel-save-as)

However, I don't understand why the `Cell.Value` returns nothing whereas the `Cell.Address` works well

My code looks as follows:

```
 Sub Creator()

     Dim ObjWorkbook As Workbook
     Set ObjWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
 "C:\my\Costs.xlsx")

     Dim cRng As Range, c As Range, Row As Range, cell As Range
     Dim strName As String, pName As String

     strName = "-Jan24-Timesheet"

     Dim i As Long

     Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("AA1:AA5")


     For Each Row In cRng.Rows
         For Each cell In Row.Cells
             Debug.Print cell.Value & strName
         Next cell
     Next Row
```

Debug.Print shows just the generic string like below

[image]

How can I get the cell value in my loop?

I used the `Debug.Print` function before I go further. I need to have a good solution at this stage before I start spitting out the documents.

Comment: Do those cells have values on the sheet? Or maybe you refer the wrong sheet `Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("AA1:AA5")` ? Try specifying it like at least `Set cRng = ObjWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("AA1:AA5")`

Comment: You can check this with `Debug.Print cell.Parent.Parent.Name`, it's likely not the one you're expecting as Vitaliy mentions.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak your solution wasn't successful. However thanks to you I've managed to get to the point.  The final formula is ObjWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Range("AA1:AA5").
Thank you very much for your hint!

Comment: `Sheet1` is an object i.e. a worksheet with the code name "Sheet1" in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`, a macro-enabled file (`.xlsm`, `.xlsb`)). So if e.g. you want to reference the `Sheet1` (tab name) worksheet in the opened workbook, you could use something like `Set cRng = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1:AA5")`.

Comment: Besides all (good) said above, since your range contains only a column, no need to iterate between rows and then between the row cells. It would be enough to use `For Each Cell in cRng.Cells` `Debug.Print cell.Value & strName` `Next Cell`...

Comment: @Geographos I didn't give you a solution, just a hint where to look for)

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak But you still cannot use `ObjWorkbook.Sheet1` ever.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but here's what I think you're trying to accomplish: you're using one workbook with macros to open another workbook at "C:\my\Costs.xlsx" which has values to use as names for more workbooks you want to save as in the other question from the link you mentioned ([Loop Excel Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171873/loop-excel-save-as)) and for now you're just tying to retrieve the values from the other workbook (Costs.xlsx).

If that's the case, here are the two approaches you could take:

1)
Here's your updated code that works on my system using the answer to the question you linked ([Loop Excel Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171873/loop-excel-save-as)) and the comments to your own question above:

[This is a screenprint of the output I get from the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY6Vj.png)

```
Sub test1()
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb2ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range, c As Range, Row As Range, cell As Range
    Dim strName As String, pName As String

    strName = "-Jan24-Timesheet"
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\my\Costs.xlsx")
    Set wb2ws1 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set cRng = wb2ws1.Range("AA1:AA5")
    Debug.Print "Opened workbook: " & wb2.Name & ", sheet: " & wb2ws1.Name
    
    For Each cell In cRng.Cells
        Debug.Print cell.Value & strName
    Next

    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False: Set wb2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. 

And here's your updated code, but Costs.xlsx doesn't flash on screen, as with the open method above, when values are retrieved:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim exlapp As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wb2ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range, c As Range, Row As Range, cell As Range
    Dim strName As String, pName As String
    
    strName = "-Jan24-Timesheet"
    
    Set wb2 = exlapp.Workbooks.Add("C:\my\Costs.xlsx")
    Set wb2ws1 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Debug.Print "Inside workbook: " & wb2.Name & ", sheet: " & wb2ws1.Name
    Set cRng = wb2ws1.Range("AA1:AA5")
    
    For Each cell In cRng.Cells
        Debug.Print cell.Value & strName
    Next
    
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False: Set wb2 = Nothing
    exlapp.Quit: Set exlapp = Nothing
End Sub
```